# Emergency Mode in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, boot

I have been using ubuntu 16.04 on my device. All of a sudden, it says "Welcome to Emergency Mode...".

I tried solutions in  various pages, including a live usb with fsck. It did not work for me.

Also, i used 'journalctl -xb', the only red lines were tpm errors.

Then I used fdisk -l to see the devices. I found something strange there. Attached image fo the result. I did not create that extended partition. How does it cover my entire disk? Also, what is up with the id? Is that the problem?

[image]